# Containers overlapping when size of window is small

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, bootstrap-4

When the window size is small(or while using it on some small screen phones) the buttons are overlapping the heading. Here's the code:

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.x2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center
}
```

```
<body>
<div style="background-color: #E9ECEF">
    <br><br>
    <center>
      <h1>Survey Management System</h1>
    <center>
</div>

      <div class="x2">
        <p><button Class="btn btn-warning" onclick="document.location = 'user/registration.html'">Register</button></p>
        <p><button Class="btn btn-warning" onclick="document.location = 'user/Login1.html'">Login</button></p>
        <p><button Class="btn btn-warning" onclick="document.location = 'admin/alogin.html'">Admin Login</button></p>
      </div>
```

I am a beginner and any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Any other suggestion that you find helpful are also welcomed.

Comment: what is your itnended layout? I'm pretty sure that you ahve an easy layout in mind where an absolute positioning is the wrong approach.

Comment: I am trying to make sure that if the window is made extremely small it doesn't overlap the header as it's doing now.

Comment: that is the job of media queries. You adjust your design accoording to different screen sizes. For example if you ahve 3 buttons in one row, media queries can change the layout that they are dispalyed below each other after going below a preset screen width. Thats why I highly recommend to start with a drawin of your intended layout for different screen sizes. Thats actually how professional start designing a website aswell. They start with a simple drawin for different screen sizes.

Comment: @RatneshNagi hello you just need text align center remove all the css it will be responsive

Answer (score 0):

The problem is absolute positioning. If you use absolute positioning, you break the links of your div from your page (if no relative positioning exists in parent).

`position: absolute` It looks the first element which has a relative position on parent level and it adjusts its position accordingly to the `relative` element. If no `relative` element exists in the parent tags, it adjusts its position accordingly to the page.

Try to give a

`position: relative;`

to your **x2** and try again. If you want to center things, you must give the top position like

```
top: calc(50% + "height of header");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, Cemil!!

I tried to change the position to relative however it didn't work. I am trying to make sure that if the window is made extremely small it doesn't overlap the header as it's doing now.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can give the sizes with percentages. I don' t know much about your project